# How to read the build target name in a CMakeLists.txt file?

Tags: cmake

I have a requirement to read the build target name, like, clean, clean-first, etc. in a CMakeLists.txt file and set few build flags that are needed for another file.

Say from command line I send this command:

C:\Program Files\CMake\bin\cmake.EXE" --build c:/cmake_example/build --config Debug --target clean --

In one of the CMakeLists.txt file, I want to read the --target value, in this case, it is "clean" and try to set some new flags.

I tried searching for CMake documentation to parse/read the build command options inside a CMakeLists.txt file with no success.

Comment: In the `CMakeLists.txt` you cannot read the name of target which build is requested. The reason is simple: `CMakeLists.txt` is executed when **configure** the project, but target name is passed to the **build** process only. It is not CMake who driver the building, it is some of the build tool, for which CMake generates build files: Make, Ninja, Visual Studio, etc. The invocation `cmake --build` is just a convenient way for call the build tool.